# ¿Cómo medir el área de un semicirculo por el metodo de los trapecios

Tags: c, calculo

Ya intenté medirlo; este código me debería dar un valor entre 9 y 10, pero me da 52600.

Me harían un parote si me corrigen lo que falla. Aparentemente es la función, pero no estoy seguro. También me serviría mucho si cambiaran la solicitud del código, y en vez de que  pida los limites, que pregunte por un radio, usando la distancia entre límites como medida de este ultimo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float f (float x){
    return 3*x*x+1; 
}
int main(){
    float a, b, si=0, area, h;
    int i,n;
    printf("intervalo a integrar, límite inferior a \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("límite superior b \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("franjas de la particion n= \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    h=b-a/n;
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        si=si+f(a+i*h);
    }
    area= h*si;
    printf("el intervalo es I(a,b)=%f\n", area);
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltan paréntesis en el cálculo de `h`. La forma correcta es:

```
h = (b - a) / n;
```

También agregue un `printf` dentro del ciclo para imprimir los valores intermedios.

Con esos cambios obtengo los siguientes resultados:

```
intervalo a integrar, límite inferior a 
0
límite superior b 
10
franjas de la particion n= 
10
h=1.000000
i=0 si=1.000000
i=1 si=5.000000
i=2 si=18.000000
i=3 si=46.000000
i=4 si=95.000000
i=5 si=171.000000
i=6 si=280.000000
i=7 si=428.000000
i=8 si=621.000000
i=9 si=865.000000
el intervalo es I(a,b)=865.000000
```

El valor exacto de la integral es 1010, así que anda cerca.

Probemos con 1.000 puntos:

```
intervalo a integrar, límite inferior a 
0
límite superior b 
10
franjas de la particion n= 
1000
h=0.010000
i=0 si=1.000000
i=1 si=2.000300
i=2 si=3.001500
i=3 si=4.004200
i=4 si=5.009000
i=5 si=6.016500
i=6 si=7.027300
    ...
i=993 si=99056.562500
i=994 si=99353.976562
i=995 si=99651.984375
i=996 si=99950.585938
i=997 si=100249.789062
i=998 si=100549.593750
i=999 si=100849.992188
el intervalo es I(a,b)=1008.499878
```

que se acerca más al valor real.

**Edición**

Elimine la modificación al limite en el ciclo `for`, dejandola como en el original.

Comment: Si añades <= al for, lo que haces es recorrer n veces + 1 el bucle. Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué si quitamos el <= no se calcula el último punto? Si, realmente, quieres 1000 cálculos, desde la posición 0 hasta la 999 hay 1000 números.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez. Correcto. Voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: con mil puntos deberíamos conseguir el valor exacto prácticamente. Puedes sustituir    tu formula para el area por la siguiente formula mejorada:  `area = h * ( ((f(a) + f(b)) / 2) + si);`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos! Ya que soy nuevo aquí la pagina no me deja dar ningún premio, ni registra mis votos, pero de verdad les debo la vida.